# How do I override the rendering of a Content Element in fluid_styled_content?

Tags: typo3, overriding, typoscript, typo3-8.x, fluid-styled-content

In TYPO3 8.7 I am trying to override the file `Textpic.html` from fluid_styled_content so that I can use my own rendering for the textpic content element.

As long as I modify the original file inside the extension itself, this is working fine.

However, I want to create my own copy of this file and use that copy. This is not working - TYPO3 does not use my own version of the file.

**Here is what I did:**

In the Setup field of my TypoScript template I added:

```
lib.contentElement.templateRootPaths.100 = /fileadmin/template/Templates/
```

Then I copied `Textpic.html` from `fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Templates` into my folder `/fileadmin/template/Templates` so that it becomes `/fileadmin/template/Templates/Textpic.html`.

Any hints, what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting constants. For example

```
styles.templates {
    templateRootPath = EXT:siteconfig/Resources/Private/Extensions/fluid_styled_content/Templates/

    partialRootPath = EXT:siteconfig/Resources/Private/Extensions/fluid_styled_content/Partials/

    layoutRootPath = EXT:siteconfig/Resources/Private/Extensions/fluid_styled_content/Layouts/
}
```

So these locations will be checked first, if no file is there for a certain contentelement, the version of fluid_styled_content will be used.

Check the original at /typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Configuration/TypoScript/constants.txt

Make sure you keep the same subfolder structure for partials.

Comment: I tried this way now as well, but no success. I have double and tripple checked the file paths and I do not see a mistake in there. Actually, I am doing exactly the same for a partial and it is working...

Comment: It should work. Did you clear cache? Are you not mixing up Textmedia with Textpic? Did you make the template changes within <f:section name="Main"> ?